# How to edit the Info.plist file in build folder

Tags: iphone, titanium, background-audio

I'm creating a live audio streaming app using titanium studio (version 3.1.1). I need to enable background audio playback for iphone. Currently background audio works in android emulator but not in iphone sinulator (when I click the home button, audio fades away and stop). I created the audioplayer and set the audioSessionMode.

```
Ti.App.player = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({
  url :'http://broadcast.infomaniak.net/radionova-high.mp3',
  allowBackground :true
});
Titanium.Media.audioSessionMode = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_MODE_PLAYBACK;
```

When I add and save the following lines to Info.plist file and run the project, the file reloads and remove these lines. How do I correctly edit this file? or is there another way to get background audio in iphone?

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
<string>audio</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

you basically add the section to your tiapp.xml.

here is a good blog post on the topic.

http://bencoding.com/2012/07/15/using-titanium-ios-specific-configurations/

Comment: Thank you, the blog was helpful. I managed to add the code lines to the info.plist file. But still the background audio does not work on iphone sinulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796157/audio-playing-in-background-not-working-in-ios-simulator

Comment: Background audio is not supported in iOS Simulator afaik.You should try it in device Thanks